# How can I put a tamed toad in a safari net?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-yogscast-complete-pack

I have a few tamed toads that I can't put in safari nets, right clicking just toggles between stay/follow. How can I still do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just be able to use a safari net launcher. This will launch your nets from a distance, avoiding right clicking on the mob accidentally.